# How to create a graph which upgrade continously after each ajax request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I want to create a graph which updates continuously after each AJAX success.

Right now i am using the following code but after each AJAX new graph created not updated.

```
function updateGraph(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/show_stats/asset/AjaxHandler.php",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response)
        {
            var result = Object.values(response);

            var resData = [];
            result.forEach(function(element) {
                resData.push({
                    x: element.xVal,
                });
            });

            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'spline',
                    animation: Highcharts.svg,
                    marginRight: 10
                },

                time: {
                    useUTC: false
                },

                title: {
                    text: 'Live random data'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Value'
                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#808080'
                    }]
                },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Connections',
                    data: resData
                }]
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I am using Highcharts. And i want to add one or more points after each AJAX request success. 
Someone, please help.

Comment: Here is sample demo for what you are looking for [link](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/live-data)